# When is a matrix-valued function convex?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

How is convexity defined for a matrix-valued function $f:\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}
\to\mathbb{R}$?

- If $f:X\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ then it is [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition) iff $f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) \leq tf(x_1) + (1-t)f(x_2)$ for any $x_1, x_2\in X$ and $t\in(0, 1)$.
- If $f:X\subset \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$ then it is [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_several_variables) iff $\Gamma = \{(x, r)\in X\times\mathbb{R}\,:\, r \geq f(x)\}$ is a [convex set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set#Definitions). That is, if for any $\gamma_1, \gamma_2\in\Gamma$ we have $t\gamma_1 + (1-t)\gamma_2\in\Gamma$ for any $t\in(0, 1)$.

How is it defined for a matrix-valued function?

Comment: You write matrix-valued but then for the codomain you still use a single R. What exactly did you mean here?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek That was a mistake sorry. I meant a function that takes values on $m\times n$ matrices. Input is a matrix, output is real

Comment: The phrase blah-valued usually means that the output values are of type blah, hence the confusion. In your case (i.e. real-valued function) all existing definitions of convexity still work perfectly when the inputs are matrices or anything else that lies in a convex set in an affine space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is not a one-answer question. Here is one possibility, define $\preccurlyeq$ to be a relation on $\mathbb R^{n}\times \mathbb R^{n}$ to be defined as $x\preccurlyeq y =1$ if and only if $x_i \leq y_i$ for all $i\in [1:n]$ (more generally you could
take $\preccurlyeq$ to be any partial vector ordering on any vector space). Let $f:X\to \mathbb R^{n}$ (or again any partially ordered vector space) some authors (for instance "A. Löhne, Vector Optimization with Infimum and Supremum.") say that $f$ is convex if and only if $\Gamma=\{ (x,y) : f(x)\preccurlyeq y \}$ is a convex set.

You can show that this is equivalent to the definition that $f$ is convex if and only if for all $x,y\in X$ and $\lambda\in[0,1]$ then $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) \preccurlyeq \lambda f(x) +(1-\lambda) f(y)$. This works only when $\preccurlyeq$ is a vector ordering

Here is the proof, since $(x_1,f(x_1))$ and $(x_2,f(x_2))$ are both in $\Gamma$ (that we suppose convex), let $\lambda\in[0,1]$, then $\lambda(x_1,f(x_1))+(1-\lambda)(x_2,f(x_2))$ is in $\Gamma$ and so $f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)\preccurlyeq \lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda)f(x_2)$. Now suppose the second property holds, and let $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ both be in $\Gamma$, let also $\lambda\in[0,1]$, then $f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)\preccurlyeq \lambda f(x_1)+ (1-\lambda)f(x_2)\preccurlyeq \lambda y_1+(1-\lambda)y_2$ (this last step uses the axioms of a vector ordering) this says that $\lambda[x_1,y_2]^T+(1-\lambda)[x_1,y_2]^T$ is in $\Gamma$ and proves its convexity according to the first criterion.

For the vector ordering proposed above $x\preccurlyeq y$ if $x_i\leq y_i$ for all $i$, this is equivalent to having convexity of all $f_i$ where $f(x)=[f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x)]^T$. Also note that there are some notion of subgradients, and almost everything we have in convex optimization, We however lose the notion of minimum in general, but you can define some other type of minimality such as $x$ attains a minimum if for all $y$ such that $f(y)\preccurlyeq f(x)$, we have $f(x)\preccurlyeq f(y)$ and you can do things like gradient descent to get to such a minimum.

This finds some nice application in multiobjective optimization, on my side I am very interested in such optimization when the objective space has and infinite amount of dimensions (but still is partially ordered).

Comment: Can you suggest more references for what you're writing here? Or is the book by Lohne enough? I find it extremely interesting!

Comment: @AspectStalence I do not know other references, some little things here I have deduced when researching on the subject but I didn't have time to go very far, I would actually be very interested in some more recent material on the subject, so if you find any, let me know.